# Riemann integral substitution with $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis

For a Riemann-integrable function $f$: $[1, e]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\int_1^e f(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(e^x)e^x dx$$

and this easily follows from more general results of Lebesgue integration theory. It's also not hard to see that $(f\circ\exp)\exp$ is Riemann-integrable since it's a.e. continuous whenever $f$ is.

Can we give an elementary proof of this equality, i.e. one that doesn't go beyond the toolbox of elementary analysis and standard Riemann integration theory?

I guess the main obstacle is that $f$ is not necessarily the derivative of an $F$, but there just might be some clever argument relying heavily on the niceness of the $\exp$-function.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something? Looks to me like you just made a substitution. $x = e^y$ means $\text{d}x = e^y \text{d}y$. Then the variable $x$ appears to be recycled. The limits of integration change accordingly as well. Unless you mean we need to prove that such a substitution can be made, given the fact that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes, your last question is just what I mean. The standard substitution rule only holds when $f$ is continuous, at least the version that follows elementarily from FTC. The rule is true in general but one needs (I think?) Lebesgue stuff to prove this - I wonder if it can be proven in an elementary way for the exp-function in particular.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Relation_to_the_fundamental_theorem_of_calculus This should answer your questions.

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is the standard proof that assumes that $f$ is CONTINUOUS so as to guarantee existence of an antiderivative.

Comment: Good point. Now I'm interested.

Comment: Rudin proves it without assuming continuity in Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Maybe have a look there.

Comment: I don't have a copy at hand. What's the main idea? Does it use some measure theory?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the general approach for proving the integral substitution rule is an approximation argument. If $f$ is a piecewise-constant function that identity clearly holds, hence the problem boils down to proving that any Riemann-integrable function can be approximated with a piecewise-constant function in a effective way. There are some natural candidates:
$$ f_n(x) = f\left(n\left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor\right), $$
for instance. Can you fill the missing details?

Answer (score 1):

The basics for a Riemann integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$: Suppose $g:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ is strictly increasing and $C^1,$ with $g(c)= a, g(d) = b.$ Then

$$\int_a^bf = \lim \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(g(t_k))(g(t_k)-g(t_{k-1})).$$

By the MVT, the last sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(g(t_k))g'(s_k)(t_k-t_{k-1}).$$

If we had

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(g(t_k))g'(t_k)(t_k-t_{k-1})$$

we'd be done. But $g'$ is uniformly continuous, so it's okay to put that in. Those are the main ideas; it's not too hard to fill in the gaps.